# Do interfaces really have no constructors?

Tags: java, list, interface

If `interface` has no constructors, then how does this code compile?

```
    interface I {
        List<Integer> LIST = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    }
```

Who initializes `List` here?

Comment: It's static by default. A Class instance is loaded and initialized for it.

Comment: `asList()` isn't a constructor.  It likely calls one inside the method, but it is probably calling the constructor for `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 5):

> Do interfaces really have no constructors?

Yes.  They cannot be instantiated.

> Who initializes LIST here?

The implicit static initializer for the interface ... which is called once before anything can use the `LIST` object<sup>1</sup>.

The fields declared by an interface are implicitly `public`, `static` and `final` ([JLS 9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3)) and any initialization is performed by the interface's static initialization ([JLS 9.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3.1) / [12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)).

---

<sup>1 - Actually, that is not strictly true.  It is possible to write a program in which a static field is used before it has been properly initialized.  (The details are in the JLS.)  But it takes some doing ... and you shouln't ...</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces do not have any constructors. The thing

```
interface I {
    List<Integer> LIST = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
}
```

compiles and works because the `LIST` is a variable of the interface and is available for all the classes which implement `I`. An interface can be thought as a common prototype for classes with same data fields and methods, i.e., all the implementors need to implement them except for variables.

The variables are initialized when `VM` loads a class which implements the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance member that is declared in an interface is static. So, `LIST` is static, final and public.

So, when you want to access a member *I* from an interface named `LIST`, you can use: `LIST.I`

but because of encapsulation, you do not want public members that are not final. 
Typically, these static final members to specific instances of the type. 
A Type refering to shapes will have a final static instance of Circle or Square.

ex:

```
Class shape {  
  public final shape Circle;  
  public shape();  
  void setX() {};  
  void getX() { return x;}  
}
```

Look at `java.lang.Long`, It has such instances for **MIN_VALUE** and **MAX_VALUE**.

Object Oriented Programming requires the use of `getX()` and `setX()` functions to maintain encapsulation.

Answer (score -1):

Interfaces by Java definition are *static*, *public* and *final* .

You cannot instantiate an interface **without** giving an *implementation* between a pair of *{ and }*.

```
new InterfaceA() { int getA() { blah...;return x} };
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that is not instantiating the interface.  It is instantiating an anonymous subclass that implements the interface.  And interface *per se* **cannot** be instantiated.

Comment: as I said "**WITHOUT** giving an _implementation_". Therefore, this is not **just** an _instantion_...

Comment: you missed my point.  I'm saying that an interface **CANNOT BE INSTANTIATED AT ALL**.  What is being instantiated is NOT an interface.

Comment: JLS 15.9.1 - "The class being instantiated is the anonymous subclass."  JLS 4.3.1 - "An object is a class instance or an array." ... not an interface instance.

Comment: I tried to highlight the borders and the terrain. You seem _intent_ on arguing ...:(

Comment: -1 - I'm not going to argue any more.  I'll just downvote because your answer is technically / terminologically inaccurate, and likely to mislead and confuse beginners.